# Show that ${240 \choose 120}$ is divisible by 242

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
{240 \choose 120} & = \frac{240!}{120!(240-120)!} 
= \frac{120! \cdot 121 \cdot 122 \cdot \cdots \cdot 240}{120! \cdot 120!} 
= \frac{121 \cdot 122 \cdot \cdots \cdot 240}{120!} \\
& = \frac{122 \cdot 124 \cdot 126 \cdot \cdots \cdot 236 \cdot 238 \cdot 240}{\;\,61\cdot\;\,62\cdot\;\,62\cdot \cdots \cdot 117 \cdot 119 \cdot 120} \cdot
 \frac{121 \cdot 123 \cdot 125 \cdot \cdots \cdot 237 \cdot 239}{60!} \\
& = 2^{60} \cdot \frac{121 \cdot 123 \cdot 125 \cdot \cdots \cdot 237 \cdot 239}{60!} 
=\frac{2^{60} \cdot 239!!}{60! \cdot 119!!}
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
{240 \choose 120} \cdot \left(60! \cdot 119!! \right) = 2^{60} \cdot 239!! 
\end{equation*}
\begin{equation*}
60! \cdot 119!! = \frac{60!}{11 \cdot 2} \cdot \frac{119!!}{11} \cdot 2 \cdot 11 \cdot 11 
= \frac{60!}{11 \cdot 2} \cdot \frac{119!!}{11} \cdot 242
\end{equation*}
$242 \mid (119!! \cdot 60!)$

$(119!! \cdot 60!) \mid (2^{60} \cdot 239!!)$

By the transitive property, $242 \mid (2^{60} \cdot 239!!)$

\begin{equation*}
{240 \choose 120} = 242 \cdot \frac{2^{59} \cdot \frac{239!!}{121}}{60! \cdot 119!!}
\end{equation*}

How do I prove that $\frac{2^{59} \cdot \frac{239!!}{121}}{60! \cdot 119!!}$ is an integer?

Comment: Hint:  $242=2\times 11^2$.  Can you show that your expression is even?  Can you show it is divisible by $11^2=121$?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Worth noting:  This is all closely related to the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number).  Indeed, the integrality of those at least implies that $121$ divides your number.  A cheap (but unintuitive) proof of that can be obtained via the (easily proven) general relation $$\binom {2n}n- \binom {2n}{n+1}=\frac 1{n+1}\binom {2n}n$$  (you would still have to show that your number was even).

Here's a direct proof:

[de polignac's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre%27s_formula) is very useful for problems like this.  It tells us that, for a prime $p$, $$v_p(n!)=\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \Bigg \lfloor \frac n{p^i}\Bigg \rfloor$$

Where, as usual, $v_p(m)$ denotes the greatest power of $p$ which divides $m$.

Now, you are interested in $$\alpha=\frac {240!}{(120!)^2}$$

Noting that $242=2\times 11^2$ we compute $$v_2(240!)=237\quad \& \quad v_2(120!)=116$$

Since $237>2\times 116$ we see that $\alpha$ is even.  Indeed, $$v_2(\alpha)=237-2\times 116=5$$

We also compute $$v_{11}(240!)=22\quad \&\quad v_{11}(120!)=10$$

which implies $$v_{11}(\alpha)=22-2\times 10=2$$ and we are done.

Comment: Very interesting solution! You should answer more often here and not always by comments!